# SQL where function used with Over Partition

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am calculation a range of figures,  one of the calculated columns are a weighted average calculation based on "Accountlink"  by "DTstamp".
The problem is that I need the final result (per accountlink) to show in a new column - each Accountlink's final result per accountlink  - to be used in a new calculation - as per example below:

```
Accountlink      WA_Calc         WA_Calc_Final
1                 20.00            30.00
1                 40.00            30.00
1                 30.00            30.00 
2                 15.00            20.00
2                 35.00            20.00
2                 28.00            20.00
```

on the image is an extract of the script I am compiling.

[image]

However, I am just getting errors.

Any assistance and/or direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. Use formatted text instead of images the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "last row", unless a column specifies that.

Let me assume you have one.  I'll just call it `?`.

Then you can use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(wa_calc) over (partition by id order by ? desc) as wa_calc_final
from t;
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the feedback. It put the old brain onto a new path. But unfortunately I cannot use a "over partition" again because then I get the error "Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate",  you will see in the above extract of my script, the over partition is already being used.